# HP LaserJet P1102w & Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 18.04, printing, hplip

Having looked at all of the questions regarding the setup of the HP LaserJet P1102w on Ubuntu (various versions) on this site (as well as many others), I'm still having no success at all.  I've tried hplip & CUPS.  If you need log files or any other information, please let me know.  It's critical that I be able to print on this printer; I have an inkjet, but many of my documents that need printed are in the 100- to 200-page range, so, needless to say, that'd use a ton of inkjet ink (and the job probably wouldn't finish printing).  Thanks in advance!

```
Steps I took to install HPLIP on 1/24/2019:
```

In Chromium, browsed to https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing

Clicked on See "All Supported Printers" (opened in a new Chromium tab) and searched for "P1102w"

found that it was listed as being supported in 3.10.4 & 3.12.6

Went back to the tab for https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing

Clicked on "Download HPLIP"

Selected "Ubuntu" as the Distro

Clicked "Download HPLIP", which opened into a new tab (sourceforge), followed by a window to save the file (I chose the "Downloads" folder) - hplip-3.18.12.run was the filename

After the download completed, I clicked on "...'click here' for installation instructions."

Seeing "These instructions assume that the hplip-3.18.12.run file was downloaded to your Desktop directory...", I moved the file from "Downloads" into "Desktop" in Files.

I then followed the instructions that the webpage enumerated, as follows:

Opened a Terminal window
   Input "cd Desktop"
   Input "sh hplip-3.18.12.run"
   Input "a" to use automatic install mode
   Input "y" to make sure the identified [Linux] Distro was correct (Ubuntu 18.04)
   Entered the sudoer's password
   Using Software & Updates, verified the following:
      that the universe/multiverse repositories were enabled
      that the main repository was enabled
      that the CD-ROM/DVD source was disabled since no Ubuntu installation media
         was inserted in the drive
   Pressed "Enter" to read the installation notes
   Answered "yes" to have the installer install the hplip specific policy/profile
   Answered "yes" to install missing dependencies
      Saw a message that 2 package managers were running; as I didn't know how to
         shut them down safely, I input "f" to force said package managers to close
      Saw a message that HPLIP-3.18.12 exists and that it may conflict with the new
         one being installed, so I input "i" to Remove and Install
   Was presented with the option to check for HPLIP Updates; input "y" to do so
   Was presented with the option to check for HPLIP Plugin Update Notifications;
      input "y" to do so
   Was presented with the option to install plug-ins in GUI mode; input "u" to do
      so

ERROR MESSAGE:
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket

followed quickly by a new window - "HP Device Manager - Plug-in Installer"

Selected the already-selected option - Download and install the plug-in from an HP
   authorized server (recommended)

Clicked Next >

After the network connection was verified, I saw this in the Terminal:

Downloading plug-in from: 
   Receiving digital keys: /usr/bin/gpg --homedir /home/mark/.hplip/.gnupg --no
   permission-warning --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys
   0x4ABA2F66DBD5A95894910E0673D770CDA59047B9

followed by a pop-up window saying:

Unable to receive key from keyserver

Without this, it is not possible to authenticate and validate
   the plug-in prior to installation.

Do you still want to install the plug-in?

```
                                            No           Yes
```

Clicked on Yes

Noticed another error message in the Terminal (a repeat of an earlier error message):

Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket

Noticed a new pop-up window with the Driver Plug-in License Agreement

Scrolled to the bottom of the lawyer-mandated text (I'm assuming the lawyers mandated it)

Clicked the box to indicate acceptance

Clicked Next >

Another pop-up window - HP Device Manager - Enter Username/Password

Username was filled in

Entered my password

Clicked on OK

In the Terminal, I saw this:

Plugin installation failed
   error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
   error: Plug-in install failed.

Simultaneously, a pop-up window appeared - HP Device Manager - Plug-in Install with the message Plug-in install failed.  Clicked on OK.

Back in the Terminal -

RESTART OR RE-PLUG IS REQUIRED appeared with explanatory text.  Since my HP
      LaserJet P1102w is wireless, input "i" to ignore/continue, as directed by
      said explanatory text

Still in the Terminal -

PRINTER SETUP appeared with an instruction to make sure the printer is connected
      and powered on (I pressed the Power button on the front left of the P1102w)

Was asked if I wanted to setup the printer in GUI mode

Input "u" to setup the printer in GUI mode

Another pop-up window - HP Device Manager - Setup - Device Discovery

Selected Wireless/802.11 (requires a temporary USB connection and is only available for select devices)

Clicked Next >

Another pop-up window - HP Device Manager - Wifi Configuration

Per the instructions, I connected a USB cable - first into the rear of the printer, followed by into a USB port on the PC

Clicked Next >

In the window (Step 2 of 5), the printer was successfully identified, so clicked Next >

Step 3 of 5 (Find and Select a Wireless Network) - selected the Wifi network SSID I wanted to connect to and clicked Next >

Step 4 of 5 (Configure Wireless) - selected the appropriate Wireless Security Type and input the Wireless Security Key, then clicked Connect

Another pop-up window which said "Waiting for printer to connect to the wireless network..."

Noticed a message in the Terminal - "warning: Request Failed with Response Code 204" and was then followed by "warning: Request failed with Response code 404.  HostName not found."

Step 5 of 5 (Wireless Configuration Results) - said the printer was successfully configured on the wireless network and was instructed to run (in the Terminal) "hp-setup [xxx.xxx.x.xx]"

Clicked Finish

"warning: Request failed with Response code 404.  HostName not found." was still showing in the Terminal.

I opened a new Terminal window and ran the command "hp-setup [xxx.xxx.x.xx]"

In the Terminal, I saw this error message again: 
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket

however

the device was found, per the Terminal display

Another pop-up window - HP Device Manager - Setup - Select From Discovered Devices - Step 2 of 3 - appeared with the P1102w identified, so I clicked Next >

Another pop-up window - HP Device Manager - Setup -

The device you are trying to setup requires a binary plug-
   in.  Some functionalities may not work as expected without
   plug-ins.

Please run 'hp-plugin' as normal user to install plug-ins.

Visit http://hplipopensource.com for more information.

Clicked on OK

Since the indented error message above was also present in the Terminal and a command prompt was not present, I opened a new Terminal window and ran the command "hp-plugin"

In the Terminal, I saw this error message again: 
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket

Another pop-up window - HP Device Manager - Plug-in Installer - Driver Plug-in Installation - Step 1 of 2

"Download and install the plug-in from an HP authorized server (recommended)" was selected, so I clicked Next >

In the Terminal, this appeared:

Downloading plug-in from: 
Receiving digital keys: /usr/bin/gpg --homedir /home/mark/.hplip/.gnupg --no-permission-warning --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0x4ABA2F66DBD5A95894910E0673D770CDA59047B9

followed by

Another pop-up window which said:

Unable to receive key from keyserver

Without this, it is not possible to authenticate and validate
   the plug-in prior to installation.

Do you still want to install the plug-in?

I clicked Yes

It went back to the Driver Installation which I had tried earlier before; I clicked Cancel

I saw this in the Terminal afterwards:

Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
error: License agreement not accepted. Exiting.
error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
error: Plug-in install failed.`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88823/discussion-on-question-by-mark-ellis-hp-laserjet-p1102w-ubuntu-18-04-lts).

Answer (score 3):

I had a simmilar issue (on a fresh install of Xubuntu 18.04), what worked for me was:

- Before connecting the printer:
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install hplip
- Connected the printer:
- hp-setup -i

The installation ran with a few basic questions and printed successfully, I hope that this helps someone (on a HP LaserJet P1102w, connected by USB)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, Guest, but I still ran into the same issues I’ve been having.  I’m a day or so away from going back to Windows 10.  I heard “Linux is so easy & everything plays well with it, and on and on and on and on...”, but Windows NEVER gave me these kinds of troubles/issues.  Like I said, I’ll probably give it another day until I go back to Windows 10.  This is ridiculous.

Comment: Disregard my request; having gotten directions from Microsoft on going from Linux to Windows 10, I’m doing so.  If Linux makes more use of the GUI in the future, maybe I’ll use it.